# Making knitr optional

Tags: r, latex, knitr

When writing a paper I generally use `knitr` to embed tables and plots that I generate in R. All of this works exceptionally well for me. However, some of my coauthors are not as enthusiastic about this workflow and would much rather just leave interactions with `knitr` to me and concentrate on writing their sections without having to bother with the R code. They would also much rather not have to install R, RStudio and various packages.

So, is there any way of typesetting LaTeX documents with embedded `knitr` chunks without having to run them through R first? Is there a way, in other words, to simply ignore the chunks during the typesetting process (or perhaps to replace them with dummy tables/plots)?

Comment: You could write in `.Rtex` format, which keeps the R chunks as LaTeX-commented lines: see https://github.com/yihui/knitr-examples/blob/master/005-latex.Rtex

Comment: @BenBolker Excellent! Thanks for the pointer. That means, however, that the chunk has to be completely self-contained, right? I can't have a chunk that produces an `\includegraphic{}` and wrap that chunk in a `figure` environment because regular LaTeX will choke on empty floats.

Comment: or try to remove multi-line delimited chunks .. . http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10226/multiline-pattern-match-using-sed-awk-or-grep ?

Comment: `knitr` chunks will auto-generate figure environments, captions, etc. for you; if you're willing to have the 'raw' version simply missing the figures (rather than having empty figures), you can use a chunk like `<<myfigure,fig.cap="myfigure">>` (which you would refer to via `\ref{fig:myfigure}` -- although your co-authors would end up with missing references).  Could you just add a `\ ` or something to make the figure not completely empty?

Comment: I'm embarassed I didn't know `knitr` can generate entire figure environments for me. That should take care of that problem (the missing references ought not to be a problem). One last problem I can think of before I actually try this out: inline `\Sexpr{}`s

Comment: Extending @BenBolker's `.Rtex` suggestion, you could set `include=FALSE` for each of the figures and then insert them explicitly with your own calls to `\begin{figure}; \includegraphics{}; \caption{\label{}}; \end{figure}`. Your coauthors, when they don't have access to the figures created by knitr, can compile the document with placeholders for the figures by setting `\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}` in the document's preamble. With this approach, references will end up pointing to the appropriate figures, which will at least be identifiable by their captions.

Comment: there was a [feature request for this](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/536), but it got sort of side-tracked and closed, unfortunately.

Comment: I think this is an important use-case not well covered by existing packages. Ideally, knit() would have an option 'untangle = TRUE' to produce a working document for non-technical coworkers, and appropriate (commented) hooks to sync it back with the original literate programming document.

Comment: One more thing that might make the workflow suggested by @BenBolker and @JoshO'Brien easier in practice: Is there any way to tell RStudio to treat files with extensions other than `.Rnw` as `knitr` documents?

Comment: I fear this may have gotten lost in the discussion above I can see that the Rtex-style chunks suggested above would work to isolate the chunky bits. But how would I keep the LaTeX compiler from choking on in-text `\Sexpr{}` commands?

Comment: something like `\renewcommand{\Sexpr}{\texttt}` maybe?

Comment: That'll work. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Update: revised description [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/19DHWpxZ8JYYF3ynjHljuegpNX4wub1F8zBhjdvwf02w/edit?usp=sharing)

This does not answer the exact question, but maybe the use case. I had a similar challenge recently: I wanted to combine the writing and analysis in one `.rnw` file, but my collaborators didn't want to use R/RStudio/GitHub/LaTeX.

So I decided to share a subfolder of my git repo with them via Dropbox. This folder contains three `.docx` files: `introduction.docx`, `methods.docx`, and `discussion.docx` (I write the results section within the `.rnw` file). The only catch is that they have to use some very basic LaTeX when writing, e.g., `\subsection{heading}` for headings, `\cite{key}` for references, ``quotes'', escaping \%, \$, and \&.

Back in the `.rnw` file, I convert the `.docx` files to `.txt`:

`system("textutil -convert txt introduction.docx")`

and then rename the file extension from `.txt` to `.tex`:

`file.rename("introduction.txt", "introduction.tex")`

Then outside of the `R` code chunks, I call in the `.tex` files with:

`\input{introduction}`

I posted a [small example](https://github.com/ericpgreen/SO/tree/master/collaborate) to GitHub.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@biblabel}[1]{\quad#1.}
\makeatother
\date{}
\bibliographystyle{plain}

\begin{document}

\begin{flushleft}
{\Large
\textbf{My Title}
}
\end{flushleft}

\section{Introduction}
% do not write in this section...let collaborators write in introduction.docx

<<intro, include=FALSE>>=
# assumes wd set to root folder collaborate
# convert docx to txt
  system("textutil -convert txt introduction.docx")
# rename txt to tex
  file.rename("introduction.txt", "introduction.tex")
@

% pull in introduction.tex
\input{introduction}

\section{Methods}
<<methods, include=FALSE>>=
  system("textutil -convert txt methods.docx")
  file.rename("methods.txt", "methods.tex")
@

\input{methods}

\section{Results}

<<results>>=
  dat <- data.frame(x=runif(30, 0, 30))
  mean <- mean(dat$x, na.rm=TRUE)
@

The mean is \Sexpr{round(mean, 1)}.

\section{Discussion}
<<discussion, include=FALSE>>=
  system("textutil -convert txt discussion.docx")
  file.rename("discussion.txt", "discussion.tex")
@

\input{discussion}

\bibliography{example.bib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is nice (you could get even fancier and read the sections in from Google Docs, for example)! But what I am really looking for is a way for my coauthors to be able to use knitr documents the same way they would any old LaTeX document, that is, I want them to be able to typeset the document themselves without my help.

Comment: Thanks. I think Google Docs would work too. My collaborators are pretty traditional Word/track changes folks, but I could see how Google Docs would be nice.